# preg_match function does not work with if statement?

Tags: php, find, cpu-word

I am trying to use the function pre_match on a string that saved in array element `$lines[$i]`.

The string is like that "Keywords: Antarctica; Landsat-8; ASTER; Regional geology mapping; Northern Victoria Land".

Although the string contains the /Keywords/, all the time the program go to the else part and shows me "not here".

Any help why is that??

Thanks in advance

```
$lines = file('C:\Tamer\Open Polar\New Keywords\Original citations files\combined.txt');
// Loop through our array

$length = count($lines);
for ($i = 0; $i <= $length; $i++) {

    settype($lines[$i], "string");              // Be sure that everything is string

    if(preg_match("/Keywords:/",$lines[$i]))
        {
            echo "we got it" . "<br />\n";
            }
        else
            {
            echo "not here" . "<br />\n";
            }
        }
```

Comment: "// Be sure that everything is string" - every line in the file __is__ string.

Comment: `$i <= $length` should be `$i < $length`

Comment: could you please share the part of the file with this/these lines and the surrounding 2-3 rows?

Comment: I test with random txt file contain Keywords: and work..

Comment: This is your code https://3v4l.org/rO83E  (I've changed `<=` to `<`) it outputs `we got it<br />`

Comment: Hi mitkosoft this is the part of the file that contains the word "potentially provide quantitative information regarding the degree of weathering.
Keywords: Antarctica; Weathering; Oxidation; Hyper-arid environment; Hypothermal environment; Equotip; Mars"

Answer (score 1):

Use strpos/stripos [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.strpos) since it's faster anyway.

Settype is unneccessary, since the file will be parsed as string.

```
$lines = file('C:\Tamer\Open Polar\New Keywords\Original citations files\combined.txt');

$length = count($lines);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) 
{
    if(strpos($lines[$i], 'Keywords:') !== false)
    {
         echo "we got it" . "<br />\n";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "not here" . "<br />\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: For me it is working. Tested here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f22a1101f9a759a91d8175d784d20bfabe338982

Maybe check your file.

if($file == false) 
{
    die('file is false');
}